# Is it possible to create a custom cdk init template to leverage pipenv for my python project?

Tags: aws-cdk

I would like to utilize pipenv as my virtual environment manager and for my dependency management for my Python cdk projects, upon running 'cdk init'. I read that you can specify a 'custom' application template but could not find documentation on creating one. Is it possible and can the virtual environment/dependency manager be controlled using this feature?

I would like to be able to run 'cdk init hello-world --language python' and have the scaffolding for the project be generated BUT using pipenv.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that without modifying the source code for the CDK package itself. You likely won't want to manage your own divergent version of the standard package.

I've shoe-horned CDK to work with PipEnv a couple of times, and it's more work than it's worth at this point. The problem is that PipEnv forces the `.` delimiter in the package name to a `-`; `pipenv install aws-cdk.aws-rds` is listed as `aws-cdk-aws-rds` in the Pipfile, and the package installations don't actually work.

There's an open issue on the repo for this though (https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3671), so you could +1 there in hopes that they can address it. It really is an issue with Pipenv though.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link from Scott for the open issue, it looks like this works now, provided the package name is in quotes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).